# Cookie name security

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

Is it a security hole to name each session with the username of the user currently logged in?

example:

```
//Alice has login
sessions_name('Alice'); sessions_start(); //Alice has login
//When Bob Logs in
sessions_name('Bob'); sessions_start(); //code follows for Bob
```

etc....

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I'm trying to create a login system just for educational purposes. I've read somewhere that session_id can be stolen and user Eve can (using the stolen SessionID from Alice) can login as Alice. So, I thought that naming the SessionID as the username of the user currently logged in and regenerate it every (let's say 2 hours) decreases the possibilities of session hijacking. Am I right?

Comment: Security aside, you'd find this hard to implement.  You can't tell if Alice or Bob is logged in without starting a session, but you can't start a session until you pick a session name.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your session name with be `PHPSESSID` (unless you rename it with [`session_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) - like you've proposed). This really gives no extra benefit in terms of security, here's why;

You've mentioned that you're aware sessions can get stolen, which is correct ([session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)), though the name itself (`Alice`, `Bob`) introduces no security measure in this (not even by having different names for each user).

The `session_name` is something that will allow your application to reference the session with a more obvious meaning. (Ie: It makes no sense if `PHPSESSID` to hold session data about a form in terms of scanning code - `PHPSESSID` doesn't reference `form` in any way - this is a vague example, but you understand).

**So we have identified the risk, but why having dynamic `session_name` not help with security?**

Generally, a session hijack will be done via XSS exploit. This vulnerability will execute Javascript on the clients/targets machine and send you (the attacker) their cookies (session values and session names are included. Having the session value makes it a full cake).

The attacker will send themselves the cookies by creating a request (usually HTTP) to a webserver they own with post data of [`document.cooke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

**In conclusion**

Naming the session dynamically isn't a security flaw in itself. The session won't "work" without the correct value & name. Your main concern should be binding the session value to the client, by;

- Binding the session value to the users user-agent
- Binding the session value to the users IP

You should also look into [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) so that if an attacker did get your session id, they'd have to be quick enough to hijack it before the value regenerates.